# Python NamedTuple C-struct pack interpretation

Tags: python, struct

I have a multiple questions how to transfer C-struct into python. Here is an C input:

```c
struct stE220_Header {
   uint8_t cmd;
   uint8_t startAddr;
   uint8_t length;
};

struct stE220_Cfg {
   struct stE220_Header cmdHeader;

   uint8_t ADDH; // E220_REG_ADDRESS_CFG
   uint8_t ADDL;

   struct stSpeed { // E220_REG_SPEED
      uint8_t airDataRate:3;
      uint8_t uartParity :2;
      uint8_t uartBaudRate:3;
   } speed;
   struct stOption { // E220_REG_TRANS_MODE
      uint8_t transmisstingPower:2;
      uint8_t :3;
      uint8_t RSSIAmbientNoise:1;
      uint8_t subPacketSetting:2;
   } option;
   uint8_t channel; // E220_REG_ADDR_CHNL
}
```

I was able to transform part of it into python. (But maybe without a right way.)

```py
class StHeader(NamedTuple):
    cmd: c_uint8
    start_addr: c_uint8
    length: c_uint8


class StCfg(NamedTuple):
    # class StHeader cmd_header
    # Q: How to include StHeader class here without allocation?

    ADDH: c_uint8
    ADDL: c_uint8
    # // E220_REG_SPEED
    class StSpeed(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ('airDataRate', c_uint8, 3),
            ('uartParity', c_uint8, 2),
            ('uartBaudRate', c_uint8, 3)
        ]
```

I tried a different way...

```py
class StHeader(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('cmd', c_uint8),
        ('start_addr', c_uint8),
        ('length', c_uint8)
    ]


class StSpeed(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('air_data_rate', c_uint8, 3),
        ('uart_parity', c_uint8, 2),
        ('uart_baudrate', c_uint8, 3)
    ]


class StCfg(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('cmd_header', StHeader),
        ('ADDH', c_uint8),
        ('ADDL', c_uint8),
        ('speed', StSpeed),
        ('option', StOption),
        ('channel', c_uint8),
```

It more-less works, but, isn't it possible to add it into nested class like

```py
class M():
    class stA(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ('a', c_uint8)
        ]

    class stB(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ('stA', stA),
            ('b', c_uint8)
        ]
```

It can't find the `stA` symbol, while is nested.

So lets focus on the second part of the problem. How to interprets the data (bytes) as structure?

```
data = b'\xc1\x00\x08\x00Zb\xc0\n\xd3\x00\x00'
st = StCfg()
# interprets data as s StCfg structure without copying

# did not work, missing method
st.from_buffer_copy(data)

# Q: This works fine, but does not have some side effects?
memmove(byref(st), data, sizeof(st))
```

Is it ok, what I did?

//Edit: Ok, it was ok for the whole time, just a wrong syntax. But how to use `Union` in `BigEndian` is not available for Python 3.9?

Thanks

Comment: Nesting the structs in another class won't work because functions or nested classes in Python can't "see" the outer class namespace when they are inside a class body. Just declare all structs you need outside any classes, and use the class only to associate instances of the structs as needed, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```py
from ctypes import Structure, c_uint8


class StOption(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("transmisstingPower", c_uint8, 2),
        ("three", c_uint8, 3),
        ("RSSIAmbientNoise", c_uint8, 1),
        ("subPacketSetting", c_uint8, 2),
    ]


class StHeader(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("cmd", c_uint8),
        ("start_addr", c_uint8),
        ("length", c_uint8),
    ]


class StSpeed(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("air_data_rate", c_uint8, 3),
        ("uart_parity", c_uint8, 2),
        ("uart_baudrate", c_uint8, 3),
    ]


class StCfg(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("cmd_header", StHeader),
        ("ADDH", c_uint8),
        ("ADDL", c_uint8),
        ("speed", StSpeed),
        ("option", StOption),
        ("channel", c_uint8),
    ]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = b"\xc1\x00\x08\x00Zb\xc0\n\xd3\x00\x00"
    st = StCfg.from_buffer_copy(data)
    print("data in:", bytes(st).hex(' '))
    print(f"cmd: {st.cmd_header.cmd}")
    print(f"air data rate: {st.speed.air_data_rate}")
```

And got the output of:

```
data in: c1 00 08 00 5a 62 c0 0a
cmd: 193
air data rate: 2
```

Comment: Ahaa, I was wrongly using it. So the key is to use `StCfg.from_buffer_copy` and not `st = StCfg()` and then `from_buffer_copy`. What about difference between the `memmove`?

Comment: `bytes(st)` and `StCfg.from_buffer_copy(data)` should be all you need in Python3. ctypes.memmove emulates the memmove of C with complete faithfulness. If you tell memmove to copy more bytes than sizeof(self), you will overwrite memory that you do not own, with indeterminate consequences, arbitrarily delayed.

Comment: Ok, I'm fine with that. Thanks